# "Cannot use import statement outside a module" after installing babylonjs using npm

Tags: javascript, npm, babylonjs

I've been trying to install babylonjs via `npm`. I've set up a new project and started with `npm init`. After that I installed babylonjs with `npm install babylonjs --save` according to their documentation.
Now I created a JavaScript file to import their module using `import * as BABYLON from 'babylonjs';`. When I open the console it throws me this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

Since I'm relatively new to it I'm not quite sure if I'm missing an important step. I don't want to use their CDN, because I won't have access to the internet all the time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the es6 packages, which fit better when using es6-style imports.

Here is the documentation:

https://doc.babylonjs.com/features/es6_support